# Format as Table an Array of Object

Tags: powershell, powercli

i want to format as table an Array of PSObject my code is:

```
$object = @()
Foreach ($Alarm in Get-AlarmDefinition) {
    Foreach ($AlarmAction in Get-AlarmAction -AlarmDefinition $Alarm) {
        $obj = New-Object PSObject -property  @{Definition = $Alarm.Name; Action =""; GY=""; YR=""; RY=""; YG=""}
        Foreach ($AlarmActionTrigger in Get-AlarmActionTrigger -AlarmAction $AlarmAction) {
            $obj.Action = $AlarmAction.ActionType
            If ($AlarmActionTrigger.StartStatus -eq "Green") {
                $obj.GY = $AlarmActionTrigger.Repeat
            } Else {
                If($AlarmActionTrigger.StartStatus -eq "Red") {
                    $obj.RY = $AlarmActionTrigger.Repeat
                } Else {
                    If ($AlarmActionTrigger.EndStatus -eq "Green") {
                        $obj.YG = $AlarmActionTrigger.Repeat
                    } Else {
                        $obj.YR = $AlarmActionTrigger.Repeat
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $object += $obj
    }
}
$object | Format-Table Definition, Action,GY,YR,RY,YG -auto
```

But returns this error:

> ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

Can some please Help?
TNX

Comment: What do you get when you remove the pipe to format-table?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try setting up the format for the table before you call the "Format-Table"

Like this:

```
$myformat = @{Expression={$_.*one*};Label="*name*";width=10},   
@{Expression={$_.*two*};Label="*Two*";width=50},  

$Result = $object | Format-Table $myformat -Wrap | Out-String  
Write-Host $Result
```

[Microsoft's Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849892.aspx)

Comment: Tnx!!!it's work like this too (without format definition): $object | Format-Table Definition,Action,GY,YR,RY,YG -auto | Out-String